# It seems impossible to normalize $ψ_± (x)=A_± e^{±i(2nπx)/L}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

I'm solving Griffiths Quantum mechanics 3rd, problem 2.46

> A particle is around 1D circle line whose circumference length $L$, then $ψ(x+L)=ψ(x)$.

I got a function below.

$$ψ_± (x)=A_± e^{±i(2nπx)/L}.$$

Now, I tired to normalize, however

$∫_0^L|A_± e^{±i(2nπx)/L} |^2  dx$

$=|A_± |^2  L/(±i(4nπ)) ∫_0^Le^{±i(4nπx)/L}  dx$

$=|A_± |^2  L/(±i(4nπ)) [e^{±i(4nπx)/L} ]_0^L$

$=|A_± |^2  L/(±i(2nπ)) (1-1)$

It's impossible. What's going on?

The solution say the normalizing factor is $1/√L$ but doesn't show me how can do this.

Comment: $\vert e^{ix} \vert = 1$ for real $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your complex algebra is messed up:
$$
|e^{2\pi i n x/L}|^2= e^{2\pi i n x/L} e^{-2\pi i n x/L}=1.
$$

Comment: I forgot |a|^2 is conjugate product, not just square... This was very stupid things.